# Creating my own 'data type'

Tags: c++

I want to be able to create a type that has 3 floats (x,y,z). I have tried:

```
typedef struct
{
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
} Vertex;
```

But that didn't work.

Does this have to be declared somewhere where it can be seen by `main`? How would I go about creating getter methods and other methods for a type I have made?

Comment: What part of it "failed"? Can you provide some hint on the error(s)?

Comment: uh, read any book about C or C++ basics?

Comment: C++ "Vertex was not declared in this scope"

Comment: getters/setters are not really applicable to structs. They are found in classes, which would be found in C++, not in C.

Comment: This is C, not C++. You are declaring an unnamed struct, and typedefing it. Since the struct has no name, it can't have a non default constructor for instance. Please consider using `struct Vertex { float x, y, z; };` instead.

Comment: Please remember to always specify your language.

Comment: Very sorry about my lack of information and all, first time using this site... let alone any site for asking questions :P will try to be more specific in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this have to be declared somewhere where it can be seen by main?

Yes.  Typically the class or struct is declared in a header file, which you `#include` in whatever translation unit (c file) you use it in.

Comment: Iv'e placed it in the same file as main where most of my methods are, so i assumed it would 'see' it like it does the methods :S

Comment: @Curtis:  At this point, you should probably post more code.  Post where you declare the struct, and where you're trying to use it.

Comment: Vertex vert = {1,2,3}; in main and struct Vertex
{
 float x;
 float y;
 float z;
}; after main.... (this is after the changes from what everyone on here is saying :S) not working

Comment: @CurtisJC: That's not very readable. Better to post the *complete* source listing in your main question (you can edit your own question to make changes to it), rather than bits and pieces in comments.

Comment: @Curtis struct Vertex needs to go _before_ main()

Answer (score 5):

How I'd do it in C++. See main() for example usage. *N.B. This hasn't been compiled or tested.*

```
#include <iostream>

class Vertex
{
public:
  // Construction
  Vertex(float x,float y, float z) : x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}

  // Getters
  float getX() const {return x_;}
  float getY() const {return y_;}
  float getZ() const {return z_;}

  // Setters
  void setX(float val) {x_ = val;}
  void setY(float val) {y_ = val;}
  void setZ(float val) {z_ = val;}
private:
  float x_;
  float y_;
  float z_;
};

int main()
{
  Vertex v(6.0f,7.2f,3.3f);
  v.setZ(7.7f);
  std::cout < "vertex components are " << v.getX() << ',' << v.getY() << ',' << v.getZ() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: this does exactly what i want :)

Comment: I downvote this for not using public variables where they are completely correct.

Comment: @Alexandre C. His question asked about get() methods! What does "completely correct" even mean?

Comment: @PUK: You prefer writing `p.x` or `p.getX()` knowing that 1) the class will never change 2) there are x,y and z member variable, it is a secret for nobody 3) getters and setters are evil ?

Comment: @Alexandre C. Well, it depends what the app/lib requirements are and how this might grow in the future. It is a secret for me that getters and setters are evil. As the OP said, it does exactly what he wants, so it fits his requirements. Any assumptions you have made are therefore "completely wrong" :)

Comment: "how this might grow in the future": I never saw a Point3D class grow out of control...

Comment: @Alexandre C. "out of control"? "completely correct" "setters and getters are evil". Where do you get these? You've never heard of the notion of a Vector generalised to n dimensions where n is a template parameter? (think: linear algebra).

Comment: You mean stuff you don't write yourself (`std::vector`, `boost::array`, ...) ?

Comment: @Alexandre C. Well, who do you think writes it? Programmers!

Comment: People who don't write Point3D classes with getters and setters. I'll stop this discussion here.

Comment: @Alexandre C. Well I just did, and it was exactly what the OP was looking for. I don't remember the OP asking someone to come along and make sweeping generalisations on how all Vector classes should be implemented. If there was one solution to this problem, then we'd all be #including <TheOneAndOnly/Vector3D.h> wouldn't we?

Comment: There is a whole world of difference between a fully fledged vector class (which exists in the standard library) and lightweight 3D point classes, both in usage and implementation. And I think that one of these evolving into the other reflects poor design skills. But that was not the point (no pun intended): writing getters or setters are a hint that your design may be bad. Not always, but most of the time. Classes should not expose data, only behavior. Here, we only have a collection of 3 variables, we could barely call this a class, and you want to write six (!) methods.

Comment: Think about it this way: in what respect is your design superior to `struct Point3d { double x, y, z; }` ?

Comment: wow, seems like quite a heated debate :S if it helps i think just being able to write p.x to return what x is would be better, but i would also want to write other methods to go with it, for instance a normalising method, treating it like a vector or calculating normals for polygons and so on. it looks a lot easier to create methods in a class like the getters and setters, but yeah im still pretty new to this, are then any advantages or disadvantages between a struct and a class???

Comment: @Alexandre C. "in what respect is your design superior to ..." I never made such a claim. Anyway, I thought you were stopping the discussion? :) I apologise for being arsey (and I admit that I am) but you got my back up by *downvoting* my response. There was nothing wrong in what I had written as what I was demonstrating what what the OP was *really* asking for - a way to create a class with members, and demonstration of controlled access to the members. The question wasn't really about the particular typical usage of a 3d point or vector class. Sometimes you need to read between the lines!

Comment: @Alexandre C. So in summary, I thought the downvote was unnecessary. Why should you damage my reputation because I was thoughtful and helpful enough to come up the goods? I'm quite new here... Is this how Stackoverflow works? Anyway, I've spent far too much time on responses to you, so I'll not view this topic again as I've got some development to do!

Answer (score 1):

Using C, this works for me

```
typedef struct { float x; float y; float z; } Vertex;

int main(void) {
  Vertex a = {42, -42, 0};
  if (a.x + a.y + a.z == 0) return 1; /* warning about comparing floating point values */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *guessing* he still gets "not declared in this scope" because he didn't say anything about a *different* error, and most people would notice if they got an error but of a different kind. At the very least the output message would *look* different.

Comment: im getting an error message saying Vertex was not declared in this scope, im using C++, iv'e pretty much got it exactly how it is in this answer minus the if statement

Comment: What compiler are you using? With what options? (note I don't know C++; some things may be different between the 2 languages)